# getting field ‘clisession’ has incomplete type error

Tags: c++

i am new to cpp and c.

i am trying to pass a variable to setter method ,in this process 2 classes are involved and  they are in different directories (i mean different package in terms of java).

i want to read a true or false value for that i created 2 cpp files

svn path: /home/abc/confid/

file1 path: /home/abc/confid/sources/Builds/Demo/rsmo/MO

file2 path: /home/abc/confid/sources/Components/Agents/CLI/code/embeddedMIND/Sessions/

and getting a error like this:/home/abc/configd/sources/Builds/Demo/rsmo/MO/Demo.h:36: error: field ‘clisession’ has incomplete type

(Line no:36 CLISession clisession; )

this is what i tried

**File1 path: Demo.h**

```
#few more header but can't show
#include "../../../../Components/Agents/CLI/code/embeddedMIND/Sessions/CLISession.h"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace DemoMethods {
}
namespace CLISession{
class CLISession;
extern char hintFormattedString [];
extern char hintDisplayString [];
extern char enable[5];

class Demo : public embeddedMIND::Addins::SingletonMO
{
public:
    typedef embeddedMIND::Addins::FormattedStringRanges< hintDisplayString, embeddedMIND::Addins::R2< embeddedMIND::Addins::StringR, 0, 255 > > DisplayString;
    typedef embeddedMIND::Addins::SingletonMOID DemoMOID;

    Demo(id_type classId);
    void Demo (char enable);
    CLISession clisession;

private:
    virtual embeddedMIND::Framework::ErrorCode sendToSource();
    virtual embeddedMIND::Framework::ErrorCode populate();

    embeddedMIND::Addins::GenericAttribute< DisplayString > enable;
};

}
#endif //DEMO_H
```

**File1 path cpp: Demo.cpp**

```
#include "Demo.h"
#include "commonapi.h"

namespace eM = embeddedMIND::Framework;
namespace Adds = embeddedMIND::Addins;


Demo::Demo(id_type classId)
: Adds::SingletonMO(classId)
  , enable(this, 10, embeddedMIND::Framework::Attribute::readWrite, embeddedMIND::Framework::Attribute::optional)
{
}

eM::ErrorCode Demo::sendToSource ()
{
    char temp[10];

    bzero(&temp,10);
    if(enable.isDirty())
    {
        strcpy(temp,enable.baseType().toString().c_str());
        if(strcmp(temp,"yes") == 0)
          strcpy(temp,"true");
        else if(strcmp(temp,"no") == 0)
          strcpy(temp,"false");
        else
           return eM::ErrorCode::InvalidValue;
    }
    clisession.setDemo(temp);
    return eM::ErrorCode::OK;
}

eM::ErrorCode Demo::populate ()
{
  /*
     Implement your code here
   */
  return eM::ErrorCode::OK;
}
```

here i am trying to pass temp value to another function clisession.setDemo(temp);

**sample code of reference class cpp file: CLISession.h**

```
#headers

class CLISession : public embeddedMIND::Addins::ThreadedAgentSession, public embeddedMIND::Framework::EventListener
{
public:
    void setDemo (char *enable);
    void getDemo (char *enable) const;
    char *demo_enable;
}
```

**sample code of reference class cpp file: CLISession.cpp**

```
#few more headers
#include "CLISession.h"

//code for other functionality
bool CLIAgent::CLISession::authenticate()
{
if(demo_enable){
//function call
}
}
void CLIAgent::CLISession::getDemo(char *demo_enable) const
{
    strcpy(demo_enable,this->demo_enable);
    //return demo_enable;
}

void CLIAgent::CLISession::setDemo(char *demo_enable){
    bzero(demo_enable,sizeof(demo_enable));
    strcpy(this->demo_enable,demo_enable);

}
```

my requirement is to get a temp value from Demo.cpp into CLISession.cpp

please help me with this error
thank you

i added these lines in Demo.h

```
CLISession* getCLISession() const { return clisession; }
CLISession* clisession;
```

now getting this error

Demo.cpp:29: error: request for member ‘setDemo’ in ‘((Demo*)this)->Demo::clisession’, which is of non-class type ‘CLISession*’

Comment: Hint: try removing the forward decl. `class CLISession;` in `Demo.h`.

Comment: after tried this getting this error bro:-  Demo.h:34: error: ‘CLISession’ does not name a type ( line no 34: CLISession clisession;)